# JdbcPagingItemReader issue with table name aliases in INNER JOIN SQL for DB2 SortKey

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am trying to write a `JdbcPagingItemReader` for an `INNER JOIN` SQL.

DataBase is DB2.

SQL is doing `INNER JOIN` on two tables so uses table name aliases to join column names. `SORT_KEY` column is present in both tables.

QueryProvider adds these two things in my query for **page - 1** onward queries ( i.e. not for first page but second page on wards ),

1.`AND ((SORT_KEY > ))` in WHERE CLAUSE

2.`ORDER BY SORT_KEY ASC`

While setting sort key column,

1.if I don't specify table alias, I get this SQL error for WHERE clause of point#1 above **-203 A REFERENCE TO COLUMN column-name IS AMBIGUOUS**

2.If I specify table alias for sort key column in `queryProviderBean.setSortKey()`, I get error for `ORDER BY` clause of above point # 2 that **Column name doesn't exist**.

Issue seems duplicate of [this jira ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-1848)

A hack is mentioned in that post but no fix.

I am not sure how to fix issue? By adding a custom query provider or by organizing SQL itself?

I am using spring batch version 3.0.7.

I really need to use `JdbcPagingItemReader` as I can't afford to read whole data in one go and I have only one table column which is a candidate for page sorting and that column is present in both tables being joined.

First page query work normal, its only **remaining pages** query that creates problem. Query is like below ,

```
SELECT ta.SORT_KEY FROM A ta INNER JOIN B tb ON ta.SORT_KEY=tb.SORT_KEY WHERE ta.COLUMN_A=?
```

`queryProviderBean.setSortKey("SORT_KEY")` and `queryProviderBean.setSortKey("ta.SORT_KEY")` both fail as described above.

Comment: Can you try wrapping your query in a subquery? E.g.: `SELECT SORT_KEY FROM (SELECT ta.SORT_KEY FROM A ta INNER JOIN B tb ON ta.SORT_KEY=tb.SORT_KEY) mysubquery`. This way there wouldn't be any ambiguity and you could use the  `queryProviderBean.setSortKey("SORT_KEY")` command

Comment: actually , I put a simplistic example in question. I have a `WHERE` after `INNER JOIN` too and without that `WHERE` inner query will return huge data. Batch query providers need `selectClause`, `fromClause` and `whereClause` separately and I don't have a way to put that WHERE in `selectClause` containing inner query. I have updated query in question to make it more clear.

Comment: Ok, and what about wrapping the B table renaming the SORT_KEY? `SELECT ta.SORT_KEY FROM A ta INNER JOIN (SELECT SORT_KEY as SORT_KEY_B from B) tb ON ta.SORT_KEY=tb.SORT_KEY_B `

Comment: That works on db2 prompt, let me fit it in java program. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Would inner query `(SELECT SORT_KEY as SORT_KEY_B from B) tb` affect memory usage of program as I guess I am loading full table in memory? By the way, syntax works in Spring Batch.

Comment: It shouldn't..  Databases have query optimizer that should recognize that's just an alias (but if you can,  check if the execution plan is different from the expected)

Comment: @SabirKhan - Are you able to solve this issue ? How to use nested or inner query in `OraclePagingQueryProvider` ?